# How to pass prototype function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm a newbie to javascript and I need some help.
I was trying to sum radius by function, but got an undefined error:(

```
function sumWithFunction(func, number) {
    return func() + number;
}

function Circle(X, Y, R) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.r = R;
}
Circle.prototype.getRadius = function () {
    return this.r;
}
Circle.prototype.increaseRadiusBy = function(number) {
    this.r = sumWithFunction(this.getRadius, number);
}

function addFivetoIt(func) {
    func(5);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a function a reference to another function, and the passed function is therefore losing scope! Here's the offending line:

```
Circle.prototype.increaseRadiusBy = function(number) {
    this.r = sumWithFunction(this.getRadius, number);
}
```

JavaScript objects are in some ways simpler than they appear. When you added the `getRadius` method to the `Circle` prototype, you were not defining a class method like you would in classical OO. You were simply defining a named property of the prototype, and assigning a function to the value of that property. When you pass `this.getRadius` as an argument to a static function, like `sumWithFunction`, the context of `this` is lost. It executes with the `this` keyword bound to `window`, and since `window` has no `r` property, the browser throws an undefined error.

Put another way, **the statement `this.getRadius()` is actually saying "execute the function assigned to the `getRadius` property of `this`, and execute it in the *context* of `this`.** Without calling the function explicitly through that statement, the context is not assigned.

A common solution to this is to add an expected argument to any function which receives another function, for context.

```
function sumWithFunction(func, context, number) {
    return func.apply(context) + number;
}

function Circle(X, Y, R) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.r = R;
}
Circle.prototype.getRadius = function () {
    return this.r;
}
Circle.prototype.increaseRadiusBy = function(number) {
    this.r = sumWithFunction(this.getRadius, this, number);
}

function addFivetoIt(func, context) {
    func.apply(context,[5]);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy, myCircle);
```

A simpler, but less robust solution would be to declare a function inline that can access a context reference in the local closure.

```
function sumWithFunction(func, number) {
    return func() + number;
}

function Circle(X, Y, R) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.r = R;
}
Circle.prototype.getRadius = function () {
    return this.r;
}
Circle.prototype.increaseRadiusBy = function(number) {
    var me = this;
    this.r = sumWithFunction(function() {
        return me.getRadius()
    }, number);
}

function addFivetoIt(func) {
    func(5);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(function(number) {
    return MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy(number);
});
```

But by far the simplest solution is to use a newer feature of ECMAScript, a function method called `bind`. [It is explained well here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), including the fact that it is not supported by all browsers. That's why a lot of libraries, like jQuery, Prototype, etc., have cross-browser function-binding utility methods like [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
function sumWithFunction(func, number) {
    return func() + number;
}

function Circle(X, Y, R) {
    this.x = X;
    this.y = Y;
    this.r = R;
}
Circle.prototype.getRadius = function () {
    return this.r;
}
Circle.prototype.increaseRadiusBy = function(number) {
    this.r = sumWithFunction(this.getRadius.bind(this), number); // or $.proxy(this.getRadius,this)
}

function addFivetoIt(func) {
    func(5);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy.bind(MyCircle)); // or $.proxy(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy,MyCircle)
```

Comment: Underscore also has a few binding tools: [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll).

Comment: Wow, deatailed! Thanks!never expected that difficult. need some time to digest...

Comment: @muistooshort True! Almost every library does, including [Ext](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-bind), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function:bind), [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_bind)...you get the idea.

Comment: so much to read just to learn that I just needed to use the 'bind' keyword. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing with [`this` in JavaScript is that it contains the object the function was a property of *when it was called*](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/this) by default. So when you pass `MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy` as a parameter, you then call it as `func()`, so the function isn't a property of any object. The easiest way to set `this` is to use the `call()` function:

```js
function addFivetoIt(func, context) {
    // The first parameter to `call()` is the value of `this` in the function
    func.call(context, 5);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy, MyCircle);
```

The below approach, setting `func` as a property before calling it, also works. You would never do this in practice because it adds an unnecessary property to `context`, but it's a good didactic example to show how `this` works.

```js
function addFivetoIt(func, context) {
    context.func = func;
    context.func(5);
}

var MyCircle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
addFivetoIt(MyCircle.increaseRadiusBy, MyCircle);
```